# How to test whether pandas.Series contains only certain type (e.g. int)?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to test whether a pandas.Series() contains ONLY integers. None of the things below work. I would prefer solutions that use `isinstance()`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy
print(isinstance(pd.Series([1, 2]).dtype, numpy.int64))
print(isinstance(pd.Series([1, 2]).dtype.type, numpy.int64))
print(pd.Series([1, 2]).dtype)
print(isinstance(pd.Series([1, 2]).dtype.type, int64))
# False
# False
# int64
# NameError: name 'int64' is not defined
```

I assume this question must have been addressed already, though I don't find it when I search for it.

Comment: You could just do ````pd.Series([1,2]).dtype == 'int64'````

Comment: Cautiously, `print(pd.Series([1, 2]).dtype == numpy.int64)` works. But that would be a break with the `isinstance` trend being better in Python. I don't know if there are corner cases where this would fail.

Comment: Do you want to know if a series *contains* a data type (i.e., it's okay to have some other data types) or if a series is solely certain data type?

Comment: `series.dtype == 'int64'` is a horrible way of checking. If a series is originally mixed, and you change some elements so that only integers are there, `dtype` may still continue to be `object`

Comment: I updated the question. Its about testing whether ALL records are of type int.

Comment: @Sören well now I'm confused. I rewrote the title based on your code but now you're suggesting you have mixed types in a column?

Comment: I don't like the new title. I think it will not show up in most searches.

Comment: @roganjosh I suggest to confirm that the series contains exclusively integers. Not if some (or any) records are integers. Not sure where I suggest mixed types. I don't think I did that.

Comment: @Sören nowhere did I suggest that you had mixed types. The edit to the title was to suggest the _opposite_ but you complained and I changed it back. You'll also see that I was critical about an answer demonstrating mixed types. Are you sure you're really upset with me over this or other people, because I've done nothing against what you're suggesting?

Comment: You are over interpreting my comments. I am not upset with you. I appreciate your efforts. Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you know the series has only one data type, you could just do
`print(s.dtype == 'int64')`

When it contains multiple data types, the data type of the series would be "object" in which case you might want to check if every element is int:

```
s = pd.Series([1,'5'])
s.apply(isinstance,args = [int])
>> 0    True
   1    False
   dtype: bool

s.apply(isinstance,args = [int]).all()
>> False
```

Comment: Instead of summing an applying `> 0`, you can just do `if series.all()`

Comment: I really have reservations about this answer. The OP didn't give mixed types, for a start.

Comment: @RafaelC in this case, probably ````series.any()````. Edited.

Comment: @xyzjayne `any` if you want to know if the series *contains* an integer; `all` if you want to know if this is a series of integers

Comment: @roganjosh That's true, but to answer the question in the title -- whether a series *contains* a given data type -- this might be more comprehensive.

Comment: @xyzjayne I'll give you that, but none of the question content matches the title. I have a feeling you knew what the OP intended to ask.

Comment: Removed my downvote. The question is confusing because I reworded the title and now it seems that the title might have been correct and all of the code was misguided. :/

Comment: Now we know for sure... @roganjosh

Comment: Well, I think you should not rename a question based on an unconfirmed answer. That's almost mean. What if the question gets down-voted after your changes?

Comment: @Sören I'm not sure what you're saying. I renamed the question, then you complained, so I changed it back to exactly what you started with. It is _you_ that has renamed the question.